# Move focus to a text field programmatically on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following text fields inside a bootstrap modal.

```
<input id="text_box1" />
<input id="text_box2" />
```

When a button is clicked, i need to focus the second textbox.

I have tried the following code but doesnot seem to work

```
function focusSecondBox() {
   $('#text_box2').focus()
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: did you add the onclick event to button?

Comment: Where is your button HTML? And as above, where are you adding the button event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the working answer below:

---

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input id="text_box1" />
  <input id="text_box2" />
  <button id="btn">Focus Input 2</button>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#btn").off("click").on("click", focusSecondBox);
    });

    function focusSecondBox() {
      $('#text_box2').focus()
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the click event, and after that focus the box.

It would look something like this.

```
$( "#yourButtonId" ).click(function() {
  $( "#text_box2" ).focus();
});
```

For more information check the documentation of JQUERY in this link:
[Jquery focus documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: As you can see in the question, this is exactly what i am doing but doesnt seem to work

Comment: @prajeesh in your question you are not getting the `click` event anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to bind a click event to the button which executes the function which then in turn focuses on the input.

```js
function focusFirstBox() {
  $('#text_box1').focus()
}
function focusSecondBox() {
  $('#text_box2').focus()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text_box1" placeholder="text box 1">
<input type="text" id="text_box2" placeholder="text box 2">
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="focusFirstBox()">focus 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="focusSecondBox()">focus 2</button>
```

Read more about jQuery's [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) binding methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id1").click(function(){
        $("#text2").focus();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
span {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="text1" value="test"/>
<input type="text" id="text2" value="test"/>
<input type="button" value="test" id="id1"/>
</body>
</html>
```